# JQuery can't show hidden element (checkbox) after .show()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, simple-form

Right now I'm solving one huge mystery why JQUery don't show my hidden input in my RoR web application. This code may not be alright (I'm very new to JQuery or JS) but I wonder why it won't show my hidden element but change the label with the logic I want even though it's in the same code block.

Do you have any reasonable explanation why checkbox.show(); won't show the element? Do I have to select the checkbox with different selector or something like that? 
JQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      var checkbox = $('#event_halfday');
      $('#others #event_start_at').datepicker().on('changeDate', function () {
          var start = $('#others #event_start_at').val();
          var end = $('#others #event_end_at').val();
          if(start != end) {
              if($('#event_halfday').attr('type') == 'hidden') {}
              else {
                  checkbox.val("0");
                  checkbox.hide();
                  $("label[for='event_halfday']").text("You can't create event where From: is not the same as To: as a halfday.")
              }
          }
          else {
              $("label[for='event_halfday']").text("Is this a halfday event?")
              checkbox.show();
          }
      });
  });
```

That checkbox is generated thanks to the simple_form gem so it look's like this `= f.input :halfday, label: "Is this a halfday event?", :default => false` and generated http is:

```
<div class="form-group boolean optional event_halfday">
    <input name="event[halfday]" type="hidden" value="0" />
    <label class="boolean optional checkbox" for="event_halfday">
        <input class="boolean optional" id="event_halfday" name="event[halfday]" type="checkbox" value="1" />Is this a halfday event?</label>
</div>
</div>
```

Thanks for any responses and for your time. Have a nice day!

Comment: Do you have any element with id `event_halfday`? If element exists, how is it being hidden - with some extra class or standard `style='display: none'`.

Comment: Yes, it's in the "question" post. It's hidden with JQuery call .hide(); on it.

Comment: Any chance you have firebug or similar tool installed on your browser. If so try running `('#event_halfday').show()` manually form the console. Also check styles on a checkbox and its parents.

Comment: When I call $('#event_halfday').show() in firebug console, it will return me instance of object[ ] but it doesn't show the checkbox:(

Comment: Is it literally `object[ ]` or is there anything between hose brackets?

Comment: There nothing. It looks like .hide(); would really hide it and its inaccessible now. Is it possible? Because when the checkbox is not hidden and I call .show() on it, it returns Object[input#event_halday.boolean]

Comment: Have you made a typo in your comment or is it really `#event_halday`. It looks like your checkbox doesn't exist when you try to show it. `hide()` should not be responsible for it unless someone has overriden this method. (Which would be just nasty and should never, ever happen!). Could you check out it after it is hidden (whether it exists in a DOM)

Comment: It was just a typo:) sry. Yes, it seems so. And for sure it wasn't overridden by me nor anyone else. And yes, the truth is that when I meet the condition to hide the checkbox it dissapear with this line of http source code: <input class="boolean optional" id="event_halfday" name="event[halfday]" type="checkbox" value="1" />

Comment: When I call $('event_halfday').length when it's hidden it returns 0. Sry if it doesn't help, it's the only way I know to find out if it exists in DOM.

Comment: Typo again? (Should be `$('#event_halfday')`). You could use firebug HTML to see current DOM.

Comment: Firebug html show this when checkbox is visible:
<input type="hidden" value="0" name="event[halfday]">
<label class="boolean optional checkbox" for="event_halfday">
<input id="event_halfday" class="boolean optional" type="checkbox" value="1" name="event[halfday]">
Is this a halfday event?
</label>
and this when it's hidden and it's supposed to be seen:
<div class="form-group boolean optional event_halfday">
<input type="hidden" value="0" name="event[halfday]">
<label class="boolean optional checkbox" for="event_halfday">Is this a halfday event?</label>
</div>

Comment: Oh my god how stupid am I?....Yes it's typo again...I was trying it with #, don't worry:) Sorry for this. I'm getting crazy because of this or something

Answer (score 2):

you can try changing this:

```
if($('#event_halfday').attr('type') == 'hidden') {
```

to this:

```
if($('#event_halfday:visible').length == 0) {
```

or

```
if($('#event_halfday').is(':hidden')) {
```

so to me your final code should be like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      var checkbox = $('#event_halfday');
      $('#others #event_start_at').datepicker().on('changeDate', function () {
          var start = $('#others #event_start_at').val();
          var end = $('#others #event_end_at').val();

          if(start != end && checkbox.is(':visible')) {
              checkbox.val("0");
              checkbox.hide();
              $("label[for='event_halfday']").text("You can't .....")
          } else {
              $("label[for='event_halfday']").text("Is this a ...")
              checkbox.show();
          }
      });
  });
```

---

#### update:

change your if condition like this using `&&` instead of another `if` in `if`:

```
if(start != end && checkbox.is(':visible')) {
```

Comment: Thanks;) That code is just in development and this has nothing to do from final code:) but this seems more nice, thx:)

Comment: But the problem is, that checkbox.show(); doesn't actually show the element even though this part of the code is called (I know it because the label change)

Answer (score 1):

That's because .show() displays items using CSS, so if you've hidden an element using CSS (via `display: none`), .show() will apply `display: block`. However, your element is explicitly hidden via the `type` attribute, thus CSS is irrelevant in this context. To display the item, you might need to do this:

```
checkbox.attr('type', 'radio');
```

Comment: that type is actually checkbox but even though i did checkbox.attr('type', 'checkbox'); it doesn't work:(

Comment: Since jQuery doesn't allow the removal or the changing of the type attribute, you may want to try this: `checkbox[0].removeAttribute('type'); checkbox[0].setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');`

Answer (score 1):

So I have solved this problem with this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var checkbox = $('#event_halfday');
$('#others #event_start_at').datepicker().on('changeDate', function(){
  var start = $('#others #event_start_at').val();
  var end = $('#others #event_end_at').val();
  if(start != end && checkbox.is(':visible')){
    checkbox.val("0");
    checkbox.css('display','none');        
  } else {
    checkbox.css('display','block');

          }
}); 
});
```

Problem was also with changing label for this input. When I changed, the checkbox doesn't show up again.
Thank's to everyone!

Comment: Ah, obviously! It is always easy when you find it. :)

Comment: Yea:) But thanks a lot BroiSatse! I dearly appreciate your help:)

Answer (score 0):

From what you're asking.. I think this is what you're wanting:

```
if(checkbox.is(':visible')){ //do things }
else { checkbox.show(); }
```

Example of basic checking procedure : http://jsfiddle.net/9yfkd/1/

Comment: I'm not sure about the rest of the OP code but `if($('#event_halfday').attr('type') == 'hidden')` seems wrong, especially when `$('#event_halfday')` is already `var checkbox`. There's no point in re-creating when you can call from the variable. That's why they're there. This simply checks to see if `checkbox` is visible, and if not, do things.

Comment: I changed this part of code like user Jai said (thanks to you Jai) but it doesn't matter. There is no mistake in if/else logic. That part of the code where checkbox.show(); is is called but it won't show the element.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to accomplish, but `$('#event-halfday')`'s type is a checkbox... hidden has nothing to do with type. If your CSS is set to `display:none` or you have hidden it with `checkbox.hide()`, then `checkbox.show()` will work. Your if statements seem wrong. Also: show/hide does not change opacity, so if you have opacity set to 0 and use `checkbox.show()`, it won't work. It just changes it to `display:block`

Comment: @Samah check the fiddle I added to the answer. You'll see that if the condition is met: IF the box is visible, it hides it. alternatively, it shows it. 1st condition still has to be met for both nested statements.

Comment: That's the point then. I know that if/else logic is fine because the label change and it's in the same code block as checkbox.show();. I've done nothing with opacity before or after hiding so I guess it's not the point.

Comment: Check this one.. using your code and a simple if statement... http://jsfiddle.net/yQX5T/

Comment: It seems like the problem is in the rest of my code. Problem is that #event_halfday selector won't return anything when it's hidden.

Comment: As it shouldn't: The checkbox will only return (via submission) if it's actually *checked*. When hiding it, *if it's checked* it will still return it's value. This is cosmetic only. Good luck!

Comment: I didn't want value, I wanted that object so i can show it again. I don't know why is it ok in fiddle and is not ok in my application...

Comment: As long as the condition leading up to show/hide is correct, the object will always be there as `checkbox`.

Answer (score 0):

A hidden input field is supposed to remain hidden.I think what you want to do is use a normal input field of the type text and hide it using css. Then you are able to show it using jQuery.

And then rest of the code `show()/hide()` for checkbox will work accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Check [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sethuramanP/s9HQP/1/)

** HTML **

```
      <div class="form-group boolean optional event_halfday">
    <input name="event[halfday]" type="hidden" value="0" />
     <input class="boolean optional" id="event_halfday" name="event[halfday]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
    <label class="boolean optional checkbox" for="event_halfday">
       Is this a halfday event?</label>
</div>
</div>
```

** Jquery **

```
    var checkbox = $('#event_halfday');
var start = "01-04-2014";
          var end =  "05-04-2014";
          if(start != end) {
              if($('#event_halfday').attr('type') == 'hidden') {}
              else {
                  checkbox.hide();
                  $("label[for='event_halfday']").text("You can't create event where From: is not the same as To: as a halfday.")
              }
          }
          else {
              $("label[for='event_halfday']").text("Is this a halfday event?")
              checkbox.show();
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

try 
`$checkbox.show();
$checkbox.hide();
$checkbox.value(0`